# React Ag Grid GetColumnState - flex is always null

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am trying to save the state of cloumns in a AG grid table.

I have found this page in the AG grid documentation
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-state/#width-and-flex

In this documentation it is written that when getColumnState() is called, both width and flex are returned.
However in my case and also in the examples on the documentation flex is always null.

How do I get the flex values of the columns instead of the width values?

#######

UPDATE

I found new infos in the docs. https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/27.1.0/react-data-grid/column-sizing/

> If you manually resize a column with flex either via the API or by
> dragging the resize handle, flex will automatically be disabled for
> that column.

However my problem is still not solved.

- Is it possible to recalculated the flex values of the columns or is there any other approach?

#######

Comment: The documentation says that width and flex are returned if flex is active on the column. Are you sure that flex is active on the column in question?

Comment: I think so. Each column in my table has a flex value. Or do I have to activate it in any other way?